# How to use bash for loop with sed to search and replace the string in a file repeatedly?

Tags: bash, loops, sed

I am not very familiar with bash programming. And I tried to write a bash script to reduce my work.
what I want is to open the in.lammps file in every folder in this directory and replace some string in the in.lammps file. but it shows such an error.
and I also did try:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in temp-*;
do
        cd $file;
        sed -i -f mycommands "$file/in.lammps";
done
```

here is the content of the file 'mycommands':

```
s/0.080/0.039/g
s/2.45/2.93/g
s/2.625/3.382/g
s/Pt/AU/g
```

do you have any idea about it ? I have 20 folders in this directory and I need to replace some string in the file in.lammps.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMs3U.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnwz3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjLbe.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Just post the text. Once you `cd $file;` you are in that directory.

Comment: ok.sorry for the link. I just wanted to make it clear. I know that the function of cd $file, but I don't know why the sed function doesn't work.  because it did work when I directly type in the command line but not in bash script.

Comment: You do `cd $file;`; but after the sed command, you also have to cd back: `cd -`.

Comment: One you `cd $file` you change your working directory. To reproduce in terminal, first `cd` into the directory, and then, after `cd`-ing into that directory, run `sed .... '<the directory name again>/in.lammps'`. Once you are in that directory, `sed ... '<relative directory name>/in.lammps'` will not exists, because you changed your current working directory,

Comment: at first i wrote in this way :[sed -i -f mycommands "in.lammps"] but it also gave the error message ' NO such file or directory' . @KamiCuk

Comment: yep! you are right. I missed 'cd ..' in this file and now it seems works well. thanks !@Roadowl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diving in directories on each iteration with `cd` would just add unneccessary complexity to your code. Simply write

```
for file in */in.lamps; do
    sed -i -f mycommands "$file"
done
```

This will detect all `in.lamps` in sub-directories and apply `sed` to each.

Just so that you understand what's going on, you can put an `echo "$file"` before the `sed` line to output all the affected files.

Comment: Or `sed -i -f mycommands ./*/in.lammps`, as `-i` implies `-s` (treat files separately).